# How to help secure my website from people writting some beginner level code in my text fields

Tags: php, security

Ok, so I have a website where you can post comments to a certain webpage. The comments will then be echoed out onto the webpage when the user clicks the submit button. The only problem is that my website is not secure at all. I was able to screw up my own website by typing in some simple code in the text field for submitting comments. For example, I would type

```
       <script>alert("Test")</script>
```

into the comment box and submit that comment. When this comment is submitted to my website, any user that visits this webpage will then have an alert box pop up saying "Test". How can I secure my website a little bit so that if someone types in some of this code it is just displayed normally. For example, if someone were to leave that comment on my website, then my website will just display that comment and not actually run the code that the user typed into the text field. I know securing a website 100% is pretty hard, but I would like to secure my website a little bit so that it is not completely vulnerable.

Comment: You want to make sure you properly escape any user-entered values.  What you are trying to prevent is called [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to Sanitize / Filter Comments from users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446431/best-way-to-sanitize-filter-comments-from-users)

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES);`

Answer (score 0):

This particular error could be escaped via [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Should do the trick. Though there are a couple of ways you could prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing javascript or html uploads to your website is a big security hole. You should have to remove tags when processing the comment. You should do this just on the function that receives the input data from the form. For removing the tags you can use the php function strip_tags() like so:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: This is still unsafe. An attacker can submit `<a onmouseover="code to steal your cookie....">Link</a>`

Comment: nop sorry, "<a>" Would get stripped but yes you are right, they could use a <div onmouvesover="code to steal your code"> it's not the final solution but it is a start